# pg gem can't find native extensions -- PostgreSQL installed using Homebrew

Tags: macos, postgresql, bundler, homebrew

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2, which I reinstalled a few hours ago in frustration with the issues that follow.

I have installed Homebrew, and when I run `brew doctor`, it says `Your system is raring to brew`.

I have the latest Xcode with the command-line utilities.

I have installed PostgreSQL using Homebrew.

```
steven$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1
COPYRIGHT           README              homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist  lib
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json        bin             include             share

steven$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.1
iMac-001EC20A3C44-5:9.2.1 steven$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

I have a Rail app with `gem 'pg'` in its Gemfile, but I can't install the gem:

```
steven$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

It seems to be looking for pg_config and libpq, which are easy enough to find:

```
steven$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin
...     pg_config       ...
steven$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include
...     libpq           ...
```

So I've tried passing every configuration option I can think of, but none work:

```
steven$ sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin"
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin
Using config values from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin
sh: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin: is a directory
sh: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin: is a directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

steven$ sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin" --with-libpqlib="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include"
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin --with-libpqlib=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include
Using config values from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin
sh: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin: is a directory
sh: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin: is a directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -l/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

steven$ sudo gem install pg --with-pg-config="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin" --with-libpqlib="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin

steven$ sudo gem install pg --with-pg-config="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/" --with-libpqlib="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include/"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/

steven$ sudo gem install pg --with-pg-config='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/' --with-libpqlib='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include/'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/

steven$ sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/' --with-libpqlib='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include/'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/ --with-libpqlib=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include/
Using config values from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/
sh: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/: is a directory
sh: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/: is a directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -l/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include/... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

steven$ sudo gem install pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/ --with-libpqlib=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/include
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/
iMac-001EC20A3C44-5:testivate steven$ sudo gem install pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/pg_config

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/pg_config
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I eventually solved this by uninstalling everything from PostgreSQL and the pg gem right down to Bundler, Homebrew and even RVM before installing every piece again one at a time. Probably I removed more than I had to but everything worked once I put it all back together again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help anyone else or not but I had the exact same problem here with PG gem not compiling. My apps live on Heroku, and locally I use RVM, Homebrew, but for Postgres I am using **Postgresapp.com**

I also use **JewerlyBox** to give me a nice GUI wrapper around RVM. I compared my Ruby 1.9.3-p194 to 1.9.3-p286 and noticed that I had set 286 to universal. I was hesitant to uninstall everything so I just uninstalled Ruby and reinstalled with the option set to 64-bit only (platform: "x86_64-darwin12.2.0").

After reinstalling Ruby with this option, the PG gem installed without a hitch and I am back to being happy. Hope this helps someone.

[image]